# Given a line in 3D space, how do I find the angle from it to a point?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js, geometry

I have two sets of points in 3D space. I'd like to draw a line that runs through the center of both sets of points, and then find the angle from that line to each point. From there, I'll match points in the two sets up based on how close together their two angles are.

I know how to find the center of each set of points (just average them all together) and I know how to match them up (even accounting for the fact they'll wrap around), but I don't know how to find the angle from the line to the point.

Basically I'm saying I want all the points projected onto a plane that is centered on and perpendicular to the line running through the centers, and I want the angles from that line to each point on that plane.

I hope I've made myself clear... I don't have much formal training in this stuff (kind of reminds me of Diff Eq from college several years ago), so do ask if I've maybe misused a term and confused you.

I figure I can translate a solution from any other language to work for me since I assume this is mostly just language agnostic math, but I'm working with Three.JS so if your solution works in javascript/with Three.JS (here's their [Vector3 class documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3), just so you know what helper functions it provides) that'd be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It is insufficient to define an angle with just a point and a line - you need another point for the angle to represent a rotation around, e.g. the center of the other set. But what you are looking for might be *least-squares* optimization, which works with the perpendicular distance of each point from the line

Comment: @meowgoesthedog - We can define a point on a 2D plane using just its distance from the center and its angle from the axis, right? So that's the angle I'm looking for. I just need the axis to be consistent for every point. So maybe instead of a 2D plane I should say a 3D space, where points are defined as their distance from the line, their angle from that axis, and their height above or below that plane (but all I want is that angle from the axis.) Like a 3D polar coordinate system. Am I conveying what I want yet or am I still confusing?

Comment: I did take that into consideration - but how would we define such an axis in 3D space? There are infinitely many possible such axes, and I don't think there is a way of "stably" defining it, at least if the points are unconstrained

Comment: @meowgoesthedog - Okay, I see what you're saying. I don't care how the axis is defined so long as all the points use the exact same axis (both sets should share that single axis). What I'm really going for is finding which point is radially closest in the other set. So if you imagined I had a set of points from the base of a cone and a set of points half way up the cone, then I'd have pairs of points defining lines on the surface of the cone. Hope it's clear what I want now... I feel like what I want is simple in my head but difficult to put into words.

Comment: I see, it is possible to use the same axis for everything provided that it is defined from the line joining the centers, and that line does not change during the algorithm's execution. However since you want to compare radial distances, why bother with that angle at all? Your description of the setup seems to suggest that it has rotational symmetry around this line (statistically speaking), in which case defining any sort of polar angle would have no physical meaning (if I have understood correctly)

Comment: So you have sets of points, each set contains coplanar points, and the planes of all sets are parallel, and you want to draw lines between each "adjacent" set, with each line defined by the two endpoints the have that smallest angle between them when projected onto a perpendicular plane with the origin being the point where your center line intersects that plane? Am I understanding?

Comment: @Poosh - Yes, I think you're understanding. The points aren't necessarily coplanar (they probably will be, but I don't want to make the assumption that they are.)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog - I think you understand. A detail I didn't mention was I want to be able to arrange the points within each set so I know which is the clockwise or counterclockwise neighbor... I guess that also doesn't really necessitate having that angle at all, but I figured I'd just assign each point an angle and then sort within each set based on that angle.

Comment: 1) Project the points onto the plane, 2) translate them so that the point of intersection of the line with the plane maps to the origin, 3) pick the point farthest from the origin and define that as angle-zero, 4) normalize all of the points (that is, move them toward the origin or away from it, so as to put them all on the unit circle), but watch out for points on the line, 5) for each point, take the dot product of that ray with the zero-ray, then take the arccos of that to get the angle-- and you may have to choose another point to define positive angle. (I don't know Three.JS.)

Comment: That can be done ***without*** the involvement of angles. To compare two points A and B: 1) project them onto the line *orthogonally* to give C and D respectively; 2) take the cross-product of the vectors CA and DB; 3) take the dot-product of this cross-product result with the direction of the line. If the dot-product is positive, then A is an anti-clockwise rotation with respect to B when looking along the direction of the line, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

In general The *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

This follows, that the *dot* product of 2 unit vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a unit vector is 1.

```
uA = normalize( A )
uB = normalize( B )
cos( angle_A_B ) == dot( uA, uB )
```

[image: dot A B]

In *three.js* all the calculations can be done by the operations of a [`THREE.Vector3`][2]:

```
var a = new THREE.Vector3( ... );
var b = new THREE.Vector3( ... );

a.normalize();
b.normalize();

var cosAB = a.dot( b );
var angle_in_radians = Math.acos( cosAB );
```

As mentioned in the comment below, in *three.js* there is an operation **`.angleTo`**, which simplifies the things a lot:

```
var angle_in_radians = a.angleTo(b);
```

If you have 4 points `Pa`, `Pb`, `Pc`, `Pd`, which define 2 lines from `Pa` to `Pb` and form `Pc` to `Pd`, then the 2 vectors can be calculated as follows:

```
var Pa = new THREE.Vector3( ... );
var Pb = new THREE.Vector3( ... );
var Pc = new THREE.Vector3( ... );
var Pd = new THREE.Vector3( ... );

var a = new THREE.Vector3();
a.copy( Pb ).sub( Pa );

var b = new THREE.Vector3();
a.copy( Pd ).sub( Pc );
```

Comment: Finding an angle could be simplified to `var angle_in_radians = a.angleTo(b);`, without `.normalize()` and `.dot()`.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks!